# Adding rows and columns dynamically to table control

Tags: winforms

I need to create UI using winforms which is similar to the diagram. The table needs

row one   - one label and 20 buttons

row two   - combox box, box and 20 buttons

row three - combox box, box and 20 buttons

row four  - combox box, box and 20 buttons

In the column zero of the row zero, i need to add label and from next column need to add buttons
In the column zero of the row one,need combobox and button and then from column1 again buttons.

How to do add combox box and button to the same column(column zero) using the tablecontrolpanel, the width of the column zero should be not changed.

I am using table control to add the 20 buttons, but don't know how to add the button and combox box to the same column. [image: Table]

Comment: Put your ComboBox and Button inside a panel, and then put that panel in the Table cell.  Or put your ComboBox and Button inside a UserControl, same principle.  A TableLayoutPanel's cell can only hold one control.

Comment: I tried placing a table panel with in the table panel, the rows are not aligned.  the gap between the rows are different.

Comment: Can't see what you are doing.  Set the interior panel's Margin property to zero.